# Setting a password to access phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, passwords, localhost, root

I have tried adding a password to `phpMyAdmin` which I have done before on an old PC through the xampp homepage, but now when I type in `http://localhost/xampp` I am just taken to an xampp directory, and when I click **'parent directory'** I am taken to **Apache Friends Dashboard**.

I have tried to find a way to add a password through the `phpMyAdmin` site but cannot figure it out.

Here is a screenshot of the user accounts page in `phpMyAdmin`:

[image: User Accounts Page]

Can anyone assist me in finding a way to set a password to `phpMyAdmin`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go click on user and the click edit privileges. You should be able to do it from there when you scroll down. The newest version of XAMPP doesn't have the option to set a root password. Usually the user that you are using is bottom one"ROOT -LOCALHOST".

If you need to set the password of that user, just follow the same procedure.